# Using the default wordpress uploader inside plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, uploads

I'm developing a plugin which requires some files which the user must upload.

I've seen that some plugins (like WooCommerce) seem to use the internal WP uploader.

How do I use it to let wp handle file uploads admin-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you search in other question? this is the jquery script to call media uploader if u click a element media button

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function call_media_library() {
    var media_uploader;
    $j(document).on('click', '.video_media_btn', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn_uploader = $j(this);
        if (media_uploader) {
            media_uploader.open();
            return;
        }
        media_uploader = wp.media({ 
            title: 'Upload media',
            //you can change type of media 
            library : { type : 'video'},
            multiple: false
        }).on('select', function(e){
            // This will return the selected media from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
            var uploaded_media = media_uploader.state().get('selection').first();
            // Convert uploaded_media to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
            var media_url = uploaded_media.toJSON().url;
            // Assign the url value to the input field
            //this is the element where u will put the url, I give example for video
            btn_uploader.parent().closest('.input-group.input-group-xs').siblings( '.input-media-display' ).find('.mp4-media-src').attr("src", media_url);
            //this is to run video again after change
            btn_uploader.parent().closest('.input-group.input-group-xs').siblings( '.input-media-display' ).find('video')[0].load();
        }).open();
    });
}
```

and this is to call other requirement for display a wordpress media uploader , this is a php function

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_script_to_my_plugin' );
function insert_script_to_my_plugin(){
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
```

Comment: That worked! BTW it was  `media_uploader.state().get('selection').first();` instead of `media.state().get('selection').first();` on line 18 :) I also removed the `library` parameter, as I can accept all files with no restrictions. Thanks!

Comment: oh sory for that, i forgot to change, because it for another question. Yeah if u remove library u get all